# Qual a configuração do VSCode responsável pelo sistema de marcar (desmarcar no caso) as variáveis não utilizadas ainda?

Tags: visual-studio-code

O VScode por padrão deixa com opacidade menor a linha de código onde tem alguma variável, ou `import` que não foi "chamado" no código ainda. Quando instalo um theme que baixei ele desativa essa função.
No `settings.json`, qual a linha de código responsável por essa função?

Acredito que seja em uma das funções do editor, mas não localizei qual delas.

Alguém tem uma solução?

```js
"breadcrumbs.enabled": true,
"editor.renderControlCharacters": false,
"editor.tabSize": 2,
"editor.renderLineHighlight": "line",


"editor.detectIndentation": true,
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,
"editor.suggest.localityBonus": true,
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false,
"editor.formatOnPaste": false,
"editor.linkedEditing": true,
"editor.glyphMargin": false,
"editor.suggestSelection": "first",
"vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.lineHeight": 25,
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
"source.fixAll.eslint": true,
"source.fixAll": true
```

Acredito que esta em um desses, mas não achei o certo... (não sei o nome dessa função de identificação de código ainda não chamado).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baseado nesta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50930517/change-color-of-unused-variable-imports) do SOen, você pode alterar o JSON acrescentando o seguinte valor para `"editorUnnecessaryCode.border"` dentro do `workbench.colorCustomizations`:

```js
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorUnnecessaryCode.opacity": "#fff"
}
```

O código acima remove a opacidade do código:

- Desativado (sem o código de `opacity` JSON acima)

<sup>var `weather2` não utilizada no código</sup>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Ativado com o código acima:

<sup>var `weather2` não utilizada no código</sup>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível adicionar um *underline* com determinada cor para as variáveis não usadas no código, usando `"editorUnnecessaryCode.border": "#fff",` para uma cor branca, por exemplo:

<sup>var `weather2` não utilizada no código</sup>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]